# Activity Database design

Tags: database

Been doing an activity log database design. 
Asking what will be the relationships between these entities:

My entities are log book, activity, role(area), person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on what you need.

seems like people perform an activity and that gets logged...

so you would have a link table with those things:

```
log_book_table
--------------
log_id
person_id
activity_id
activity_time
```

Comment: Thanks... that is what i also taught. the log_book table will be the associative between person and activity. But i am getting confuse how to relate roles(area) between person and activity...

Comment: what does ROLE (Area) represent?if i guess - then maybe people are in roles? if so then another table with person_id, role_id

Comment: Role is the job operation of the person.

Comment: So any ideas how i can link that role table ?